# How do I set up an MTA to prevent spam relay?

Tags: smtp

I'm trying to secure my MTA against relaying spam, and am trying to understand what's involved.

For example:  Say I send an email using an Yahoo account to a Gmail account. When Yahoo is relaying the email to Gmail, does the relay take place without authentication? What do you need as the server to be able to successfully relay emails to another `smtp` server?

How do I set up an MTA to prevent spam relay?

Comment: What alphamikevictor said below.  I also wanted to add that if the mail servers are properly configured (to prevent spam relay), then in your example above Yahoo will only accept mail that is authenticated or from its proper network, and Gmail will only accept mail that's for Gmail.

Comment: My question really is, how to set up an MTA to prevent spam relay

Comment: Ah, that's not exactly what you asked.

Comment: It would help if you told us what MTA you were using.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard Exim

Answer (score 2):

Basically they perform a query for MX record of the domain, following your question, for gmail.com:

```
alphamikevictor@ges01:~ > nslookup -query=mx gmail.com
Server:         194.179.1.100
Address:        194.179.1.100#53

Non-authoritative answer:
gmail.com       mail exchanger = 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com       mail exchanger = 40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com       mail exchanger = 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com       mail exchanger = 10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com       mail exchanger = 20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com internet address = 64.233.189.27
alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com internet address = 173.194.72.27
alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com internet address = 64.233.165.27
alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com internet address = 74.125.200.26
```

For each *authorized* SMTP server you have a weigh so Yahoo's MTA will try to deliver to gmail address using this servers:

1. gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
2. alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
3. alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
4. alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
5. alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com

You can read more about MX record at WikiPedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record

Comment: So, Yahoo's MTA will be able to send the mail to GMail's MTA without any authentication? Which means that if I set up an MTA, I would be able to send mails to another domain without authentication, or in other words, spam?

Comment: As far as gmail MTA's are getting the mail for _themselves_ there is no need to authenticate (normally). You need authentication when you use Gmail MTA to send mail to another domain otherwise anyone would use Gmail MTAs to send mails all over the world. Or look with another point of view: you as an external user, how do you authenticate to other MTA system which has no relationship with you?

Comment: @user1720897 Yes, if a mail server is authoritative for example.com, you end up accepting spam for example.com.  Alas.  That's a whole other topic.  The point is more that if your mail server is authoritative for example.com, you don't *send* spam to other domains.